# jqgrid:data failed to change after reload page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I have some grid which use form edit. But after edit success then page reload the data in grid back to the beginning. Its mean that edit process is failed.

I have confused how to post this all variable into process page, because i'm use switch-case for this php page. I put some hidden action inside the form:

[jqgrid script.](http://pastebin.com/DpQa3Rgy)

```
<form id="editdefdata" class="editable">
<input id="action" name="action" value="changedefdata" type="hidden" />
<button id="defupdate"><span>Update </span></button>
</form>
```

this the data will be post to process page:

```
Problem_date:2011-06-10
Line:FA 14
Shift:N
Model:KD-R321EUD
Serial_number:116V4262
DIC:IQC
Def_class:B
Symptom:CD eject shifting
Cause:Under investigate
Symgrup:Function
Modgrup:KD
oper:edit
def_id:15
```

and this is the process or php page:

```
$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV,_ACCID,_PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("qdbase",$dbc) or die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());

switch(postVar('action')) {
      case 'oper':
                edit(postVar('def_id'),postVar('DIC'),postVar('Def_class'),postVar('Symptom'),postVar('Cause'));
                break;
        case 'deldefdata':
                //postVar blabla....
                break;
       }

function edit($def_id,$DIC,$Def_class,$Symptom,$Cause){
        $defID = mysql_real_escape_string($def_id);
        $DIC = mysql_real_escape_string($DIC);
        $Defclass = mysql_real_escape_string($Def_class);
        $Symp = mysql_real_escape_string($Symptom);
        $Cause = mysql_real_escape_string($Cause);
        $DIC=strtoupper($DIC);
        $Defclass=strtoupper($Defclass);

        $sql = "UPDATE oqc_defect SET DIC = '".$DIC."', Def_class = '".$Defclass."', ";
        $sql.= "Symptom = '".$Symp."', Cause = '".$Cause."' ";
        $sql.= "WHERE def_id = ".$defID;

echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
//echo $result;
mysql_close($dbc);
}
```

Could you tell me the correct answer for this case?

Comment: 1- are you see that new update,s effected your database or not ??? 2- you can create break point to validate this ..                   3- Are you use the fire bug to check it...

Comment: @hameed: 1.its not, no effect in my DB..2. of course I make validation..3. in console show 200 OK

Comment: nunu can you echo postVar('id') in your process.php page then check it in firebug what the response is ... is it return any value ?

Comment: @hameed: in which part that I must add the `echo postVar('id')`? because i have try to put inside case and below `echo $sql` not show result.

Comment: you can put the echo part before the switch .

Comment: I get `15` its return some value.

Comment: @nunu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1043/discussion-between-hameed-and-nunu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by my self.it's make me so glad, I'm going mad for 1 week because of this problem. All ways I have tried but for this day I have found the real answer.

**first**

If you want to post some parameters you must be check the parameter's name that will be post to server.On this case, make sure that your `colModel's name` same with your php file `(_POST,postVar, or REQUEST)`.

**second**

change the `prmNames` make same with your current parameter operation.
In this case, I need to change like:

```
prmNames: { oper:'action', editoper:'edit', id:'def_id'}
```

that's the root cause of my problem.That's why the script confuse during identifying some variable. The parameter below is the correct result:

```
Problem_date:2011-06-10
Line:FA 14
Shift:N
Model:KD-R321EUD
Serial_number:116V4262
DIC:IQC
Def_class:B
Symptom:CD eject shifting
Cause:Under investigate
Symgrup:Function
Modgrup:KD
action:edit
def_id:15

switch(postVar('action')) {
      case 'edit':
                edit(postVar('def_id'),postVar('DIC'),postVar('Def_class'),postVar('Symptom'),postVar('Cause'));
                break;
        case 'deldefdata':
                //postVar blabla....
                break;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript   your using **'id'** as the identifier for the record.
e.g

```
colNames:['id', .....
```

In your colModel I dont see **id**
I see  **def_id**

```
{name:'def_id', index:'def_id', hidden:true, width:55},
```

In your php your using postVar('id') to ge the variable
so add an id  definition to your colModel.